# How to add elements to the already existing elements instead of overwriting them in a list?

Tags: python, list, input, global-variables

I have this code here:

```
def alist():
    wor = []
    definition = []
    wele = str(input("Enter a word: "))
    dele = str(input("Enter a definition: "))
    x = wor.append(wele)
    y = def.append(dele)
    print("Words' List: ", wor, "\nDefinitions' List: ", definition)
```

Whenever I run it, I can add elements to the lists `wor` and `def`, however, whenever I run it again, it overwrites the elements I added earlier when I ran it the first time. I have avoided this problem by turning `wor` and `def` into global variables. Is there any other method other than making the two lists into global variables?

Thanks!

Comment: **def** is a python keyword don't use it as a variable name

Comment: Have your function `return` what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating new, empty lists each time you call the function. The function should take the lists as parameters and modify them.

```
def alist(wlist, dlist):
    wele = input("Enter a word: ")
    dele = input("Enter a definition: ")
    wlist.append(wele)
    dlist.append(dele)

word_list = []
def_list = []

word_count = int(input("How many words are you defining? "))
for _ in range(word_count):
    alist(word_list, def_list)
print("Words' List: ", word_list, "\nDefinitions' List: ", def_list)
```

Making the lists parameters allows you to have multiple word lists, e.g.

```
spanish_words = []
spanish_defs = []
alist(spanish_words, spanish_defs)
```

However, it's generally poor design to keep related data in separate lists, which you have to keep in sync. It would be better to use a single list of dictionaries or tuples, so all the related items (e.g. the word and its definition) are together.

Comment: Is not `word_count` in this case, similar to `range`. Is it possible to not have the user decide how many words to input? And are not `word_list` and `def_list` considered still global variables?

Comment: I don't understand your first question. The user IS deciding how many words to input. They enter the count, and then it uses `range()` to iterate that many times.

Comment: Yes, `word_list` and `def_list` are global variables, but `alist()` isn't restricted to just those variables. So you could have one pair of variables for English, another pair for Spanish, etc.

Comment: What I meant is, is there no other method other than the user deciding how many words they want to input? Does one have to use `count` or `range`?

Comment: You could ask the user in a loop "Do you want to enter another word?" and break out of the loop if they say no.

Comment: `while True: if input("Do you want to enter another word?") == "no": break ...`

Comment: Thanks, I understand how it is poor design to not put related data in reach for all of the functions, however, is there a method to not user global variables in this case?

Comment: You could use a class with class variables.

Answer (score 0):

When you append to your lists you assign it to new variables, x an y, but you never do anything with those. `wor` and `def` never change. You actually don't have to assign `append()` to a new variable, it will happen in-place.

If you want your two lists to always retain their memory of what they contain every time the function is called, then you should define them outside the scope of the function, otherwise every time you call the function you re-initiate them as empty lists.

```
l1 = []
l2 = []

def alist():
     wele = str(input("Enter a word: "))
     dele = str(input("Enter a definition: "))
     l1.appnd(wele)
     l2.append(dele)
     print("Words' List: ", l1, "\nDefinitions' List: ", l2)
```

Comment: This is what I had at the beginning, however, I am searching for a different solution other than putting in this case `l1` and `l2` outside of the scope of the function.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you're averse to defining them outside of the function, seeing as the answer you marked as accepted does exactly that, but I suppose one way to do it would be to add an if statement to see if the list contains items, and if not then create the list as an empty list.